# Mongo Mongoose Data Bridging Confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Transitioning from relational database design to "non-relational" has been interesting.

Regardless,

I have the following mongoose models set up: **Users**, **Companies**, **Jobs**, and **Applications**.

When a user applies for a job, their application is associated with the job.

One approach is therefore to nest references to the applications on the job:

```js
var JobSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    applications: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Applications' }]
});
```

And to store a reference to the User and Job on the application:

```js
var Application = new Schema({
    resumeFile: String
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
    job: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Job' }
});
```

Great, getting the applicants for any job is straightforward.

**And then the question follows, how how would I get the applicants for a user?**

I would have to store the applications on the user as well:

```js
var User = new Schema({
    name: String
    email: String
    applications: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Applications' }]
});
```

However, now - if the application document is removed (for whatever reason) I will still have "references" to that document in both the Job document and the User document. So I would be required to locate the User and the Job, obtain both documents... find the right references... remove them from nested arrays... then save both documents again.

This seems pretty ridiculous, compared to in a relational database with table joins, where this whole reference nonsense doesn't even exist. Associations are implicit.

So I'm wondering, is it the only way? (intentionally rhetorical, however I don't have a better solution).

Advice is greatly appreciated as well as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd probably go with this as an embedded schema as it probably is going to suit your usage patterns. Some points:

- **Applications as an array**. Well after some consideration, who is going to have 100's or even 1000's of applications. And even so, do they really all need to be kept?
- **Brief details** on the job embedded. That would seem like what would get displayed a lot, so it seems worthwhile to keep the things that are being used embedded.
- **Job Detail** as a linked object. The Job (or Ad) is likely to have a lot more information, but that isn't required when showing a summary for the user. Since all the document Id's are there you can still pull up the linked jobs.
- **Reverse applies**. No need to store the associated applications on a Job, the User to Job association exists on the user. So you can still get at all the applications, albeit in a separate query.

```js
var jobDetailSchema = new Schema({
    // All the details of the job
});

var applicationSchema = new Schema({
  resumeFile: String,
  job: {
    title: String,
    shortDescription: String,
    jobDetail: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'JobDetail' }
  }

},{ _id: false});

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  applications: [applicationSchema]
});

var User = mongoose.model( "User", userSchema );
var JobDetail = mongoose.model( "JobDetail", jobDetailSchema );
```

So yes this is different from the relational approach, but this is not a relational datastore.

Would you need to do some cleanup if a Job dissapeared? Well yes, but that's not too much maintenance and it shouldn't really be a pain even if the link went away. Do you want to loose an application detail just because the Job was pulled? Probably not, so this would be more or less correct.

If the whole applications embedded thing scares you too much, then okay, go with using references and cover all your queries calling `populate`. But the general model still stands as getting away from an atypical "many-to-many" modelling case. Just flatten things out a little.

As the wise man said, *"You must unlearn, what you have learned"*, young padawan. Embrace a new world rather than cling to the old one. But if it doesn't suit your project, then it's not the right tool.

Comment: Neil, thank you for providing a great analysis. Your point "this is different from the relational approach, but this is not a relational datastore." is very strong. And you are correct, it should not be a problem if the link was successful. Accept +1

Comment: @TaylorMac Sorry you had to endure the other rant. It seemed only fair, since you asked, to offer a different perspective from the "many-to-many" approach. And give a fair analysis, since you bothered to present a use case.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems pretty ridiculous, compared to in a relational database with table joins, this whole reference nonsense doesn't even exist.
>   Associations are implicit.

Mongodb is not relational,you cant expect a non relational db to behave like a relational one,so yeah,you need to manually clean up your datas or, use mongodb as intended,meaning embed applications in job documents and remove any reference to application from user.

Now some ODM (like Mongo ODM in PHP) will take care of the clean up for you,since you can apply "constraints" in the code and cascade deletetions,updates,etc... Mongoose will not do that.

If your datas are relational use a RDBMS,dont use MongoDB especially if no framework on the plateform you are coding can handle relationships for you.

Comment: It would seem more appropriate to suggest a solution of how to re-model this rather than just rant. The question does ask for another solution even with the comment that was made.

Comment: well i provided a solution, embedded documents. And it's not a rant. It's about using the right tool for the job and not mongodb ,because somebody told someone to use that.

Comment: I should reword my comment about it being ridiculous. Perhaps "relatively unnecessarily complicated" is better. As Neil pointed out, it is a different paradigm.